# Play Framework replying not modified when static assets are changed

Tags: java, playframework, assets, playframework-2.3, http-status-code-304

I moved a Play Framework Project to a new PC and everything is working fine but there is one annoying problem:
All static assets return the `304: Not Modified` header even after I edit them. And I think I found the origin of the problem, play framework replies following in curl:
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 527
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 14 Jan 2015 17:49:24 GMT
ETag: "4a0670efaaa84f8734d67d4557a7309dfe235301"
Last-Modified: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT`
The `Last-Modified: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT` part seems wrong to me.
And also when I edit something, the ETag isn't changing. This is annoying because Chrome doesn't load the changes unless I delete the cache and this makes mobile development nearly impossible.
The same thing also happens when I create a new application. It worked in my old Laptop wich had also Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [#3722](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/3722).

> Assets controller sends constant etag if path has a space in the name

Does the path to your workspace or to your assets has a space in it ? If so, remove it and try again.

I hope it helps.